# What exactly should constructor contain?

Tags: php, constructor

I'm building a scraper and currently my parsing class has about 100 lines constructor that fires about 10 methods contained in the class and some other 3rd party component code.

All these methods primarely parse the raw html and assign the final values to class atttributes.

Is constructor the right place to put this code in? if not where should it go if I want it executed on class instantiation?

Comment: I generally frown upon _doing_ something on class instantiation. Setting up variables & an environment is fine, but I leave the work in other methods. If you need it often, create a convenience function / method that does exactly that: instantiate the object, and then call the function you desire. 100 is way to long. If it does multiple things, split them out into their own (possibly private/protected) functions, if it contains multiple if/switch statements, you have a candidate for polymorphism. My general rule of thumb (with exceptions of course) is a function should be < 20 lines.

Comment: @Wrikken In some cases, it's acceptable to have something happen within the `__construct` function. Example: `__construct(){ session_start(); }` <-- A basic way but showcases an acceptable (after theres error handling) way to initiate a session via a class

Comment: @DarylGill: yes, there are exceptions, it's not 100%. However, a lot has to do with it being in the proper place. For instance, take your `session_start()`, I wouldn't expect it in something like a `new Calendar`, I can sort of allow for it in `new SomeController()`, I wholly expect it in a dedicated `new Session` object. In this case for instance, if a theoretical `Calendar` object _needs_ a session, I would rather define a `Session` dedicated class/object, and _require_ a `Session` object in `Calendar`'s constructor to make that clear (`function __construct(Session $session){ ..etc.. }`).

Answer (score 0):

Doing work in the constructor isn't really that bad any more, though for code readability and tidiness you could break specific functionality out into separate methods. You can then just call them from the constructor or even better after you instantiate your class. It will make the code more usable in the future too so if you need to use one of the methods when you instantiate the class it won't do everything in the constructor and you can call only the methods you require.

Comment: And, to add to it, defining small, isolated functions with only 1 goal makes it so much easier to employ inheritance to create an object that behaves differently just in the part you need, without having to re-implement / copy/paste most of the original function.